# Ruby strange behaviour while single assigning variables in a single line

Tags: ruby

How local variable `num_1` is assigned as `[1, 2]`?. Isn't that suppose to be `1`?

```
2.1.5 :121 > num_1 = 1, num_2 = 2
 => [1, 2] 
2.1.5 :122 > 
2.1.5 :123 >   
2.1.5 :124 >   num_1
 => [1, 2] 
2.1.5 :125 > 
2.1.5 :126 >   
2.1.5 :127 >   num_2
 => 2 
2.1.5 :128 >
```

Comment: Don't do that. Your code will be confusing to others and you can run into odd bugs. Being able to assign multiple values on a line is a cute trick but in production environments it's rarely a good thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It first assigns `2` to `num_2`, then returns a value and puts it into an array that is assigned to `num_1`

```
[11] pry(main)> num_1 = 1, num_2 = 2
=> [1, 2]
[12] pry(main)> num_1 = 1, (num_2 = 2)
=> [1, 2]
[13] pry(main)> num_1 = [1, (num_2 = 2)]
=> [1, 2]
```

If you want to assign two variables in one line, use a semicolon:

```
[14] pry(main)> num_1 = 1; num_2 = 2
=> 2
[15] pry(main)> num_1
=> 1
[16] pry(main)> num_2
=> 2
```

Comment: Or `num_1, num_2 = 1, 2`.

Answer (score 3):

While it is valid Ruby code to do single-line parallel assignments like this:

```
a, b, c, d = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foobar'
```

it is considered "bad style". See [Parallel Assignment](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#parallel-assignment) in the The Ruby Style Guide.